Using NGINX for reverse proxy on Linux Mint, I'd like to add WebDAV functionality
I am using NGINX on Linux Mint for reverse proxy functionalities. I would like to add WebDAV for service on local network but I'm not managing to.
I have a working reverse proxy configuration using NGINX and Let's Encrypt for certificates.
My current configuration, under /etc/nginx/sites-enabled is this:
server {


    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name site.obscured.for.privacy.com; # managed by Certbot

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.obscured.for.privacy.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.obscured.for.privacy.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
       
    location /ombi {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
    include /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
    }

    # This allows access to the actual api
    location /ombi/api {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
    }
    # This allows access to the documentation for the api
    location /ombi/swagger {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
    }

# Proxy to the Airsonic server
    location /airsonic {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host  $http_host;
    proxy_set_header Host              $http_host;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size           0;
    proxy_pass                         http://localhost:43546;
    proxy_redirect                     http:// https://;
  }



}


 server {
    if ($host = site.obscured.for.privacy.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80 ;
    server_name site.obscured.for.privacy.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


 }

I tried adding this location to the file but I think the interaction with the existing elements of the configuration stop it from working. Note that I would just need WebDAV on local network, not open to the internet, so security is not much of a concern. If I use this without the existing entries in the file, WebDAV work. I'm just unable to use it together with the existing functionalities.

    location /webdav {
        alias /var/www/webdav; # This maps the URL .../webdav to /var/www/webdav
        client_body_temp_path /var/tmp/nginx/webdav;
        dav_methods PUT DELETE MKCOL COPY MOVE;
        dav_ext_methods PROPFIND OPTIONS;
        dav_access user:rw group:rw all:rw;
        create_full_put_path on;
    }

Where should I place it in the existing configuration? Should I need to change something? Thanks to anybody that will help.
